# how to initialize recyclerViewAdapter with Okhttp

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, adapter, okhttp

I want to get data from google sheets with api-request (using OkHttp) and put it into RecyclerView.

ActivityChoosing.kt:

```kotlin
    class ActivityChoosing : AppCompatActivity(), CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
   
        lateinit var models : List<UserDataModel>
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityChoosingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        button_on_main = binding.buttonToMain
        button_show_choice = binding.buttonShowChoice
        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.visibility = RecyclerView.VISIBLE
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        getDataFromAPI()
        //var adapter = CustomAdapter(this@ActivityChoosing, models, this@ActivityChoosing)
        //recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    
    private fun getDataFromAPI(){
        var url: String = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/10-yIy1ZuPSjqgmXd7kO9sHobuVlpZHQnz5dMrou0cVs/values/Пн?alt=json&key=AIzaSyCxGK4SkJdp2COiHuXQdQM2Rg8QA6xIuZ0"
        val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val originalRequest = chain.request()
                val builder = originalRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                val newRequest = builder.build()
                chain.proceed(newRequest)
            }.build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.d("Mylog", "failed")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
                val source = response.body?.string()
                val parsed = Gson().fromJson(source, ReaderModel::class.java)
                models = parsed.values
                    .drop(2) // if the first row contains titles, this is how to ignore that first row
                    .map {
                        UserDataModel(
                            point = if (it.size >= 1) it[0] else null,
                            get = if (it.size >= 2) it[1] else null,
                            take = if (it.size >= 3) it[2] else null,
                        )
                    }
                    .filter { !it.point.isNullOrBlank() } // if you want it ignore the emtpy/blank nodes
                models.forEach { Log.d("Mylog", it.toString()) }
                models = models.toList()
                //var adapter = CustomAdapter(this@ActivityChoosing, models, this@ActivityChoosing)
                //recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            }
        })
    }
    }
```

CustomAdapter.kt:

```kotlin
    class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context, private val items: List<UserDataModel>,
                    private val listener: OnItemClickListener) : 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : 
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),View.OnClickListener {

        internal var tvTitle: TextView
        internal var tvDesc: TextView

        init {
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)
            tvDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description)
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        internal fun bind(position: Int) {
            // This method will be called anytime a list item is created or update its data
            //Do your stuff here
            tvTitle.text = items[position].point
            var a = if (items[position].get != null && items[position].get != "") 1 else 0
            var b = if (items[position].take != null && items[position].take != "") 1 else 0
            if (a + b == 1){
                tvDesc.text = if (a == 1) "привезти "+items[position].get else "получить " +items[position].take
            }else if (a + b == 2){
                tvDesc.text = "привезти " + items[position].get + "получить " +  items[position].take
            }else{
                tvDesc.text = "ничего"
            }

        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val position:Int = adapterPosition
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position,this@CustomAdapter,itemView)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(items[position].isSelected){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
            holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linear_content).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
        } else{
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linear_content).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
        (holder as ViewHolder).bind(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int,adapter:CustomAdapter,v:View)
    }
}
```

But function `OnResponse` in `getDataFromAPI()` does not go in main thread, that's why I cant initialize adapter there:

```kotlin
var adapter = CustomAdapter(this@ActivityChoosing, models, this@ActivityChoosing);
      recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Getting: `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

But if I put

```kotlin
var adapter = CustomAdapter(this@ActivityChoosing, models, this@ActivityChoosing);
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Into `OnCreate` after `getDataFromAPI()`, I catch `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property models has not been initialized`.

`CustomAdapter` works correctly, problem is in ActivityChoosing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep your code to initialise the `adapter` in the `onCreate` function of `ActivityChoosing`.
2. Change `items` in your `CustomAdapter` to public var so it can be updated by `ActivityChoosing`:

```kotlin
class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context, public var items: List<UserDataModel>,
                    private val listener: OnItemClickListener) : 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

3. In the `onResponse` function of the OkHttp's callback, update the adapter's `items` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the main thread:

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
    // ...
    adapter.items = models // update the items in the adapter
    this@ActivityChoosing.runOnUiThread { // run the code in the main thread
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // tell the adapter that the items were updated
    }
}
```